# Do mosquitoes squeeze in?

Tags: zoology, entomology

*Practical motivation:* I have equipped part of my windows with mosquito nets. Despite not opening the unequipped ones at night, I still have mosquitoes entering my flat. To decide whether I equip all windows with nets, I am wondering whether mosquitoes are likely to take advantage of other ways to enter the place: it is a 3-century old building, and in no way air tight. There is likely to remain gaps of about 2 mm width in many places, both at some edges of mosquito nets (although I could improve on these) but also around front door, etc.

*Zoology questions :*

Given the strategy I observe for mosquitoes who fly upfront to the net and explore randomly while hitting the net repeatedly, I am not sure they may detect a small opening away from larger ones, or will they?

I am also unsure whether they would squeeze for a distance longer than a few mm, since they do not appear to ever walk or crawl but only fly?